# C# generic class contains instance of the class that's derived from it

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I know the title is a little confusing but bear with me.

I need to do the following

```cs
class TemplateClass<T>
{
    T nextNode;
    T prevNode;
}

class Derived : TemplateClass<Derived>
{
    public int Name;
}
```

because I want `nextNode` and `prevNode` to automatically be the type of the derived class (aka. Derived)

But when I add in some methods in `TemplateClass` I get errors.

```cs
class TemplateClass<T>
{
    public T nextNode;
    public T prevNode;
    Mode mode;

    public enum Mode
    {
        isHead = 0, isTail, isMember, isNull
    }

    public void init (T previous, T next)
    {
        prevNode = previous;
        nextNode = next;
    }

    public void init (T get, Mode getMode)
    {
        mode = getMode;

        if ((int)getMode == 0)
        {
            nextNode = get;
            prevNode = null;
            get.prevNode = this;
        }
        else if ((int)getMode == 1)
        {
            prevNode = get;
            nextNode = null;
            get.nextNode = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Used the wrong \"init\" method");
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting errors on `get.prevNode = this;` and `get.nextNode = this;`

Error is as follows  :

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'prevNode' and no accessible extension method 'prevNode' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
```

I know what the  error  means, I just don't know how to get around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `class TemplateClass<T> where T : TemplateClass<T>`. See the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern

Comment: @canton7 Right that worked. Managed to compile but haven't actually used in a running program yet. Need your advice, do you notice any inifinite recursion loopholes in this method? I feel like if the template consists of only methods and fields without any instantiated object it should be fine.

Comment: No more so than any other class which has a reference to another instance of the same time. That sort of thing happens all the time with e.g. trees and linked lists

Comment: @canton7 Alright thanks alot. I've had some time to play around with this and it's working pretty well so far. Just a massive potential bug in the future for whoever is going to be tasked to maintaining my code. :)

Comment: You do see this pattern around -- it isn't *that* unexpected!